# Open link from DropBox app to My App

Tags: ios, dropbox, sharing

Is there any way to open link from dropbox app to my own App ?
I want to play audio file from dropbox app to my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this isn't specific to Dropbox.

You need to setup your app to indicate that it can open certain types of files (such as audio files). Once you do that, then any app, such as the Dropbox app, that offers an "Open In" option for those types of files will show your app as one of the options.

To learn how to register your app for certain types of files, see [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

Comment: It is already done. Its working with other apps with this kind of file but in DropBox it does not show my app, Rather it displays a button Open in, By tapping on Open in it says its exporting file and after that it opens the file in my app. But I want to open in directly rather then exporting it. is there any way ?

Comment: That must be something specific to the Dropbox app and that type of file. My app can open all kinds of files. If I run the Dropbox app and view a file, there is a "share" icon in the nav bar. I tap that and the activity view appears. "Open In" is one of the options. I choose that and see a list of apps, including my own. If I select my app (or any other really), the app is launched directly. I see nothing about exporting.

Comment: The Dropbox app have no option of "open with" though, so I don't think it is possible for Dropbox specifically.

Comment: @Lealo Yes it does. View a file. Tap the three dots in the upper right. Select Export from the menu. Then select Open In.